# WPF - i want to make mouse-evented Items in ListBox but it work only first child item

Tags: c#, wpf, events, listbox, mouse

i want to make mouse-evented Items in ListBox

But it work only first child item.

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding }" 
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Image Width="300" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Path=Path}" 
                           MouseMove="my_mouseMove"
                           MouseLeave="my_mouseLeave"/>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Helper" Width="500" Height="1" Fill="#FFD87A1D"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

1. I made an event with Image.
2. It works MouseMove, MouseLeave Events for first Item (Image)

   - these event is to move Rectagle in the range of listItems.
3. I want to know how to spread(?) this events to other items.

Comment: Please clarify as it's not clear.

Comment: @user3193287 it seems to me that you're placing `Canvas` with `Rectangle` on top of your image. If that's the case, and it covers your image, `MouseMove` and `MouseLeave` won't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

use the foreach loop in the code behind like this:

```
    foreach(YourClassName item in mylistbox.Items)
{

      //Make mousemove and mouseleave events here for item
      //this approach will implement event triggers for every item in the listbox
}
```

or in xaml do this:

```
  <Canvas>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Helper" Width="500" Height="1" Fill="#FFD87A1D" MouseMove="my_mouseMove" MouseLeave="my_mouseLeave"/>
  </Canvas>
```

hope this helps :)